# Prevent mobile redirect with file on subsite root

Tags: redirect, mobile

When people try to open a custom html using their iPhone with a link such as this: https://www.mysite.com/documentlibrary/page.html - everything works fine, but when they try to access the same content with a link such as this: https://www.mysite.com/subsite/page.html, they get an mobile redirect error message. It seems that pages accessed on the root level from a mobile device are treated differently than those in a document library.

How can I disable the mobile redirect for the page in the root of the subsite without having to perform changes in the server farm settings (i do not have that kind of admin access)?

Comment: It seems that users get an "Error: Access denied" whenever people try accessing files on the root or site level from a mobile device. If the files are placed in a library like Pages, it works just fine. It also works fine when people acess the files from their desktop PCs or iPads, so the mobile view plays a part in this.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious first question: does the user have access to the subsite? If there are different permissions for /documentlibrary and /subsite, then check the user groups and permissions.

Comment: Yes, the level of access is identical for both the document library and the subsite. When using desktop PCs, the problem does not occur - it is a mobile only issue.